# Javascript Regex matching only 2 items when i'm expecting 4

Tags: javascript, regex

This Regex `/({{(?!{*textdata.*)#\s*.[\w\.]+\.*}})/gm`
is giving me only two matches ( Expecting 4)  using regexp on chrome. When i use the same expression on http://www.regexr.com/ i get the right amount of matches.
Does anybody have a clue what could be going on?

```
var passingString = '{{#something}}{{#something}} I  THIS What  {{#something}}{{#something}}  \n asdasdas {{/something}}';
var test = /({{(?!{*textdata.*)#\s*.[\w\.]+\.*}})/gm.exec(passingString)
console.debug(test.length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) .vs [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match): exec will only generate one result at a time, requiring successive exec() calls until it generates null. Match, on the other hand, finds all matches at the same time.

If you run this, you get four results:

```
var passingString = '{{#something}} I HONESTLY CANNOT BELIEVE THIS SHIT           {{#something}} I HONESTLY CANNOT BELIEVE THIS SHIT {{#something}}{{#something}}  \n asdasdas {{/something}}';
passingString.match(/({{(?!{*textdata.*)#\s*.[\w\.]+\.*}})/gm)
```

result:

```
Array [ "{{#something}}", "{{#something}}", "{{#something}}", "{{#something}}" ]
```

If you still want `exec` you need to run it as a while loop, terminating when it no longer generates anything:

```
var arr;
while (arr = regex.exec(passingString)) {
  console.log(arr);
}
```

this will find four entries and then break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `match` :

```
passingString.match(/({{(?!{*textdata.*)#\s*.[\w\.]+\.*}})/gm)
```

returns

```
["{{#something}}", "{{#something}}", "{{#something}}", "{{#something}}"]
```

while `exec` only does one matching at at a time (and the length is due to the submatch).

Comment: It's interesting that i tried to do this 
'var test = /({{(?!{*textdata.*)#\s*.[\w\.]+\.*}})/gm.match(passingString)'  and it would not work.
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

But your example works

Comment: well... `match` is a function of `String.prototype`

Comment: Yeah, I figured. man i beat my head on this for too long.  Thanks for that though!